# How to find an element with a data attribute with unknown value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm looking for a specific element which contain a known data attribute. The actual value of the data could be anything. Example:

```
<div id="myObject">
   <div>
     <span data-some-data="anything">something</span>
   </div>
<div>
```

I'm trying to access the span tag in the above example.

I've tried something like:

```
var $theElementINeed =  $('#myObject').find("[data-some-data='" + ??? + "']");
```

But the value could be anything. So I don't know how to find the span.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I target elements with an attribute that has any value in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271424/how-do-i-target-elements-with-an-attribute-that-has-any-value-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check for the existence of the attribute then use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
var $theElementINeed =  $('#myObject').find("[data-some-data]");
```

Comment: how is find() better than just $('#myObject [data-some-data]") ? i don't understand why it's broken up into two selectors...

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271424/how-do-i-target-elements-with-an-attribute-that-has-any-value-in-css)! discussion, try:`$('element').find('[data-some-data]');`