# Is there a way to apply CSS to data- attributes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply my custom css style to only one anchor link in the div block.

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="zoom">
<a href="" class="card" data-entity-type="layout" data-entity-id="3">
<a href="" class="card" data-entity-type="flex" data-entity-id="3">
<a href="" class="card" data-entity-type="slim" data-entity-id="3">
</div>
</div>
```

// This applies to all links,

```
<style>
div.grid>.zoom>a.card {width:100px !important;display:block}
</style>
```

But, I would like to apply above css to only data-entity-type="layout". How to implement ? I don't want to use first:child-nth because the data-entity-type="layout" will not always come first.

Comment: `[data-entity-type=layout] { your css }` [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It looks like this:

```
a[data-entity-type="layout"] {
/* css here */
}
```

Attribute selectors can be generic or specific.

Also, check this post for more on attribute selectors: [How do I target elements with an attribute that has any value in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271424/how-do-i-target-elements-with-an-attribute-that-has-any-value-in-css)