# Selenium Element.get_attribute occasionally failing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.8

Given this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://covid19.apple.com/mobility')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.download-button-container a")

csvLink = [el.get_attribute("href") for el in elements]
driver.quit()
```

At the end, csvLink sometimes has the link and most times not.  If I stop at the last line in the debugger, it often fails to have anything in csvlink, but if I manually execute (in the debugger) `elements[0].get_attribute('href')` the correct link is returned.  Every time.

if I replace

```
csvLink = [el.get_attribute("href") for el in elements]
```

with a direct call -

```
csvLink = elements[0].get_attribute("href")
```

it also fails.  But, again, if I'm stopped at the `driver.quit()` line, and manually execute, the correct link is returned.

is there a time or path dependency I'm unaware of in using Selenium?

Comment: Adding a delay solves the problem - But why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with how and when the javascript loads the link. Selenium grabs it without waiting before the javascript is able to load the elements `href` attribute value. Try explicitly waiting for the selector, something like:

```py
(
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    .until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.download-button-container a[href]")))
    .click()
)
```

Reference:

- [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)
- [How do I target elements with an attribute that has any value in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271424/how-do-i-target-elements-with-an-attribute-that-has-any-value-in-css)

Also, if you `curl https://covid19.apple.com/mobility` my suspicion would be that the element exists ( maybe ), but the href is blank?